# SQL Query Regarding

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to SQL. Currently, I am learning to write complex queries.

I have three tables.
Country-- has list of country

```
-----------+-------------
 CountryId | CountryName
-----------+-------------
         1 | India
         2 | Srilanka
         3 | Pakistan
         4 | Bangladesh
         5 | Nepal
         6 | America
         7 | Japan
         8 | China
         9 | Russia
        10 | Canada
        11 | Australia
---------------------------------------
```

city - list of cities of country

```
--------+-------------+-----------
 CityId | CityName    | CountryId
--------+-------------+-----------
      1 | Chennai     |         1
      2 | Washington  |         6
      3 | Moscow      |         9
      4 | Tokyo       |         7
      5 | Beijing     |         8
      6 | Sydney      |        11
      7 | Bangalore   |         1
      8 | Nagercoil   |         1
      9 | AmericaCity |         6
     10 | Kathmandu   |         5
     11 | Dhaka       |         4
     12 | Lahore      |         3
--------------------------------------
```

Airport - list of airports in a city

```
 AirportId | AirportName | CityId
-----------+-------------+--------
         1 | Airport1    |      1
         2 | Airport2    |      4
         3 | Airport3    |      5
         4 | Airport4    |      1
         5 | Airport5    |      6
         6 | Airport6    |      3
         7 | Airport7    |      5
         8 | Airport8    |      7
         9 | Airport9    |      6
        10 | Airport10   |      3
        11 | Airport11   |     11
        12 | Airport12   |     10
        13 | Airport13   |     12
---------------------------------
```

Question: I want to retrieve all the countries with number of airports, like

```
Output:
countryName Airports
India            3
Srilanka         0
......... etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
  Country.CountryId,
  Country.CountryName,
  count(AirportID) AS Airports
FROM 
  Country
  LEFT JOIN city ON Country.CountryId=city.CountryId
  LEFT JOIN Airport ON city.CityId=Airport.CityId
GROUP BY Country.CountryId
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.AirportName, co.CountryName, COUNT(co.name) AS count
FROM Airports as a
LEFT JOIN City as c ON a.CityId = c.CityId
LEFT JOIN Country as co ON c.CountryId = co.CountryId
GROUP BY co.CountryId
```

Comment: The other answers do not address countries without cities having airports.  This one does;  it will return 0 for a country without airports.

Comment: @xQbert: No - it is currently left joining **from** airport to city to country, so it will retrieve airports with cities or countries. Changing the left joins to right joins will fix that, but the count will also need to be on airport name, not country name.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  c.CountryName,
  SUM(
    select count(*) from Airport a
    inner join City city on city.CityId = a.CityId
    where city.CountryId = c.CountryId
    ) as Airports
from
  Country c
```

Comment: This won't run on MyISAM/Linux: Table names are case-sensitive there

Comment: I don't know if the OP created all tables with an uppercase character at the beginning (like Country, Airport) and just forgot to hold the shift key for city, but regarding "countryName" you're totally right.

Comment: This was not criticising you, just a hint - if you fix your answer, I will delete the comment

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CountryName, COUNT(CountryName) AS Airports

FROM Airports INNER JOIN City ON Airports.CityId = City.CityId
              INNER JOIN Country ON City.CountryId = Country.CountryId

GROUP BY CountryId
```

Hope this will be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Country.CountryName,
  count(*) AS Airports
FROM 
  Country
  INNER JOIN city ON Country.CountryId=city.CountryId
  INNER JOIN Airport ON city.CityId=Airport.CityId
GROUP BY Country.CountryId
```